# Problem with Add new and update existing records with Data Import Wizard

Tags: import, data-import-wizard, data-import

I have an object with Name field type is auto generate. I use Name field for update existing record.

When I take an action import by Data Import Wizard. I used Add new and update existing records function.

With existing record I fill in the value for Name field.

With new record I ignore Name field.

But this is error when I import:

> "","false","false","MISSING_ARGUMENT:Name not specified:--"

By default the name field is auto generate value so we can not input it.

Is this a bug of Data Import Wizard ? How to import new records in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Name field type is auto generate, Salesforce will not allow you to Data Import will not allow to import new data with name.
So,
Instead use Salesofrce.com ID field as matching field in data import wizard, In that case even if you do not mention the Name field for existing record (see table) t will update by matching Salesforce.com ID.

[image]

[image]